# Part of web page getting cut off?

Tags: html

I have a global container div with these properties

```
#global
{
    width:1020px;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Inside of that div, I have multiple other divs, one of which has this styling:

```
#example
{
    width:550px;
    height:362px;
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:rgba(89,89,89,0.01);
}
```

This works great on a normal screen, but on low-res screens (or a small window), the left side of my "example" div gets cut off...

Is this fixable?

Problem site: http://spectech.webatu.com

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed size when setting width to pixels, you can either adjust it to a standard fixed size, which would be something like 800px or use em units which are scalable. You have a nice tutorial about this here: http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you're not using the margin: auto method like you did with the "headerBack" div. My general rule is that absolute positioning should be reserved for situations where any kind of static positioning would not work. In this case the set-width margin: auto method, which you've already used would certainly be sufficient, and it would correct the error of your content running out of the page on small screens.

EDIT: I've noticed that the CSS you gave here for "global" is different to the actual CSS on your site. You should use the CSS setup you posted here and it may just work.

Comment: I haven't updated my web site's CSS.  I'm looking at my local file for the site.

Comment: Well I can see the problem you're having on the live site and the CSS above looks like it would fix that problem. Is there any way you can update the site so we can see the problem?

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  BTW, do you mind giving me feedback on my website?

Comment: Im guessing that the problem is stemming from not having 'example' anymore, you must have removed it or changed the name.

Comment: It's a pretty solid site, you might want to use other opacity settings in conjunction with RGBA because IE won't show the opacity. I wouldn't use that font for your menus. I find it a little hard to read, but that could just be personal perference. You could try throwing around some light box-shadows for that extra little layer of depth.

Comment: Also, you probably know this already, but you're logo is stretched.

Comment: The logo's stretched?  What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Well the original size of the logo is smaller than the size of the img tag, so the image is being stretched to fit the img tag. This results in a somewhat unclear image. The size of your logo is 130 x 80 but it is being stretched to 150 x 100 by the inline style tag on the img node.